# String to double: max/min valid conversions

Tags: c++

I'm writing some unit-tests for conversions of strings to doubles using C++'s std::stod() function. However, I have been unable to find the min/max limits where the conversion throws a std::out_of_range exception. I've been searching online.

The string to be converted consists of only digits, exactly one period, an optionally a minus sign in front. No exponents, NANs, etc. Example: 999.1278, -999.1277

I'm looking for the following information:

1. The maximum double value that can be converted ok, where the right-side of the period is 0. Example: 999876.0
2. The smallest number passed the max number (as given in #1, above) which causes the std::out_of_range exception to be thrown. Example: 99987603.0
3. The minimum double value that can be converted ok, where the left-side of the period is 0. Example: 0.999876
4. The smallest number passed the min number (as given in #3, above) which causes the std::out_of_range exception to be thrown. Example: -0.99987603
5. If possible, other known limits. For example, as the values on the left/right side of the period grow and shrink, what are the new min/max values?

I don't know how feasible this is, specially #5, because of the floating-point nature of doubles.

For reference, I was able to do this with integers easily. These are the string  for int64_t conversions:

1. 9223372036854775807
2. 9223372036854775808
3. -9223372036854775808
4. -9223372036854775809

Comment: Have you tried starting with the value nan in your variable, then converting your string with stod() and passing the variable? If nan is kept after the conversion you can (var == var) to see if the value is valid or throw your exception.

Comment: Can you explain if/how `std::numeric_limits` does not solve the problem?

Comment: @Christian Hackl: std::numeric_limits<double>::max() prints a number like so: 1.79769e+308. I'm looking for the fully expanded number. min() gives: 2.22507e-308